# Increment tag value or add tag xstl

Tags: java, xml, xls

I have xml input message:

```
<Message>
    <Header>
        <Timestamp>2010-10-04T14:43:12.361-04:00</Timestamp>
    </Header>
</Message>
```

I need to pass it through xslt to have:

```
<Message>
    <Header>
        <Timestamp>2010-10-04T14:43:12.361-04:00</Timestamp>
        <Retry>1</Retry> <!-- added -->
    </Header>
</Message>
```

if Retry is not present in xml
and increment Retry value with 1, if it was there.

```
<Message>
    <Header>
        <Timestamp>2010-10-04T14:43:12.361-04:00</Timestamp>
        <Retry>2</Retry> <!-- incremented -->
    </Header>
</Message>
```

Can you please help.

I have code adding value if absent, how to enrich this to increment if tag is present:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" >
  <xsl:param name="ename">Retry</xsl:param>
  <xsl:param name="evalue">1</xsl:param>
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
     <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
     </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Header">
     <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates/>
          <xsl:if test="not(Retry)">
             <xsl:element name="{$ename}"><xsl:value-of select="$evalue"/></xsl:element>
          </xsl:if>
     </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Whats wrong with your code, or what about the code don't you understand? No one here wants to write your code for you... :/

Comment: I have no experience with xsl, old code was using java tranformation, after some design updates I need to use this. Part of transofration updated in question.

Answer (score 2):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" >
  <xsl:param name="ename">Retry</xsl:param>
  <xsl:param name="evalue">1</xsl:param>
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8"/>

  <xsl:variable name="number" select="//Retry" />

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
     </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="//Retry" />

  <xsl:template match="Header">
     <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates/>
          <xsl:if test="not(Retry)">
             <xsl:element name="{$ename}"><xsl:value-of select="$evalue"/></xsl:element>
          </xsl:if>
          <xsl:if test="Retry">
            <xsl:element name="{$ename}"><xsl:value-of select="$number + 1 "/>                 </xsl:element>
      </xsl:if> 
 </xsl:copy>
```

This is what I've done and looks like it is working.